# Format "%s" expects and agument of type char* etc, I just want to print the alphabet

Tags: c

Why can't I print the alphabet using this code?

```
void    ft_putchar(char c)
{    
write(1, &c, 1);
}

int print_alf(char *str)
{
int i;

i = 0;
while (str[i])
{
if (i >= 'A' && i <= 'Z')
    ft_putchar(str[i]);
else
    ft_putchar('\n');
    i++;
}
return (str);
}

int main ()
{
char a[26];
printf("%s", print_alf(a));
return (0);
}
```

I get this warning

> format ' %s ' expects type 'char*' but argument 2 has type 'int'

How do I print the alphabet using a string, and write function?

Comment: Make up your mind whether `print_alf` should return a string which you then print with `printf` or whether `print_alf` should be a void function that does the printing, which you should then just call without `printf`. At the moment, your code is a mixture of both.

Comment: You use initialized memory `a` . This whole code makes no sense at all

Comment: You will get a lot of negative feedback here, since there are a few things wrong with your example. Don't be too discouraged by it. Have a look at how [null-terminated C strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string) work, and then look carefully at the specification for the [`*printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make up your mind whether `print_alf` should return a string which you then print with `printf` or whether `print_alf` should be a void function that does the printing, which you should then just call without printf. At the moment, your code tries to be a mixture of both.

The easiest way is to just print the alphabet:

```
void print_alf(void)
{
    int c;

    for (c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) putchar(c);
}
```

Call this function like so:

```
print_alf();    // print whole alphabet to terminal
```

A more complicated variant is to fill a string with the alphabet and then print that string. That's what you tried to achieve, I think. In that case, you must pass a sufficiently big buffer to the function and return it. Note that if you want to use the string functions and features of the standard lib (of which `printf("%s", ...)` is one) you must null-terminate your string.

```
char *fill_alf(chat *str)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) str[] = 'A' + i;
    str[26] = '\0';

    return str;
}
```

It is okay to return the buffer that was passed into the function, but beware of cases where you return local character buffers, which will lead to undefined behaviour.

You can call it as you intended in your original code, but note that you must make your buffer at least 27 characters big to hold the 26 letters and the null terminator:

```
char a[27];
printf("%s\n", fill_alf(a));
```

Alternatively, you could do the filling and printing in twp separate steps:

```
char a[27];

fill_alf(a);             // ignore return value, because it's 'a'
printf("%s\n", a);       // print filled buffer
```

If you just want to print the alphabet, the `print_alf` variant is much simpler and straightforward. If you want to operate further on the alphabet, eg do a shuffle, consider using `fill_alf`.

Answer (score 3):

Your entire `print_alf` function looks suspicious.

- You are returning `str` which is of type `char *`. Therefore the return type of `print_alf` should to be `char *` instead of `int`.
- Your `while (str[i])` loop makes no sense at all since you are passing uninitialized memory to it. So your code will very likely corrupt the memory since the while loop will continue to run until a `'\0'` is found within the memory which does not need to be the case within the boundaries of the passed memory (`a`).
- You are not adding a zero termination character (`'\0'`) at the end of the string. This will result in `printf("%s", print_alf(a));` printing as many characters beginning at the address of `a` until a `'\0'` is found within the memory.

Here is a suggestion how to fix all that problems:

```
char *print_alf(char *str, size_t len)
{
    char letter;

    if ((str) && (len >= 27))   // is str a valid pointer and length is big enough?
    {
        for (letter = 'A'; letter <= 'Z'; letter++)   // iterate all characters of the alphabet
        {
            *str = letter;
            str++;
        }

        *str = '\0';   // add zero termination!!!
    }
    else
    {
        str = NULL;   // indicate an error!
    }

    return (str);
}

int main()
{
    char a[26 + 1];   // ensure '\0' fits into buffer!
    printf("%s", print_alf(a, sizeof(a)));
    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `print_alf(char *str)` function actually returns an integer which causes the error (it is defined to return int). When you specify `%s` to `printf` it expects characters, not numbers.

You can fix this by changing the return type of your function to char and if everything else works in your code you'll be good to go.